# Visual Studio not connecting to the correct version of MySql Server

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I have an installation of MySql Server 5.0 which I may not uninstall. However Visual Studio 2017 does not like this version, so I've managed to install MySql Server 8.0 (using the community installer 8.0.14).

I have installed the MySql for Visual Studio 1.2.8 using the installer as well, and as far as connectors/net go, I have tried 8.0.15, 6.10.8 and 6.9.12 (with 6.9.12 having the most luck in initially connecting and generating an entity framework model, but something has broken since).

The MySql CL still recognizes MySql 8.0 and the database is there and fine, but VS refuses to see or use that version, and instead what's to use MySql 5.0

Comment: If I can connect to the correct db via the server explorer in vs, it is likely fixed. Atm it's still seeing the old but not the new, even with Connector/NET 8.0.15  driver installed.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing with EF here. You need to use correct **MySql Driver** in order to connect with your DB. You can connect to Mysql version 5.5+ with EF using **MySql Connector/NET**

> #### Requirements for EF6 Connector/NET 6.10.x or 8.0.x
>
> - MySQL Server 5.5 or higher
> - Entity Framework 6 assemblies
> - .NET Framework 4.0 or higher (.NET Framework 4.5.1 or higher is
>   required for Connector/NET 6.10 and 8.0)

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html)

Comment: I have .NET Framework 4.5, I have and need to use MySql 8.0 (and the correct db is already there, and accessible via MySql CL), and lastly have EF6 assemblies.
As far as drivers go, I'm going to try uninstalling 6.9.12, installing 8.0.14 via the complete MySql Server 8.0 installer, see if it connects, then probably have to revert back to the Connectors/NET 6.9.12 driver (that is the only version I have found that doesn't crash in the wizard when creating/updating an EF model from a db, iirc that's what I did when initially making setting up this project).
Thank you for speedy response.

Comment: Few extra things to note. Windows 10 (yuck), there's a duplicate but outdated version of the db in question on MySql 5.0 (before I had made the project), and I no longer have access to reworking it via the MySql CL because of different install locations for the data but not the root access users table which now uses password encryption in 8.0 (5.0 appeared to be plaintext when I checked, and different table design too)

Answer (score 0):

So after much fiddling, I found out after this morning's reboot, the version 5 service had restarted and somehow took preference over version 8's one. Stopping it solved the issue. (And I've discovered I could probably have used v5... Key word, probably.)